nix builds wrong package
Using nix build with the flake.nix below, the build should fail since the references github repository does not exist.
Yet, whenever I build the flake, while it shows ecsdsddsdse.fghfghfghfghgfh as the package, it just builds paho-mqtt (that was referenced there a while ago).
Apparently, my nix installation somehow remembers the repository referenced a while ago (paho-mqtt) and always fetches that, regardless of what I actually write as owner and repo.
I have already removed /nix and reinstalled without any results.
Does  anyone have an idea why it fetches the wrong repo?
{
  description = "Nix flake for packaging modpoll (a Poetry application) from GitHub";

  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";  # Latest Nixpkgs
    utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";
  };

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, utils, poetry2nix }:
    let
      system = "x86_64-linux";
      pkgs = import nixpkgs {
        inherit system;
      };

      pname = "modpoll";
      version = "1.2.0";

      updatedPahoMqtt = pkgs.python3Packages.buildPythonPackage rec {
        pname = "dsfsdfsdf";
        version = "fghfghfghfghgfh";
        format = "setuptools";

        src = pkgs.fetchFromGitHub {
          owner = "ecsdsddsdse";
          repo = "pdsfsdfsdfh";
          rev = "sdfsdfsdf";
          hash = "sha256-9nH6xROVpmI+iTKXfwv2Ar1PAmWbEunI3HO0pZyK6Rh";
        };
      };

      app = pkgs.python3Packages.buildPythonPackage rec {
        inherit version pname;
        pyproject = true;

        dependencies = [
          updatedPahoMqtt
          pkgs.python3Packages.poetry-core
        ];

        src = pkgs.fetchPypi rec {
          inherit pname version;
          sha256 = "sha256-t69tvHqQNeNs3iErcq49Rcq2LtCiQkmNiVxhGZtMaF8=";
        };
      };
    in
      {
        packages.x86_64-linux.default = app;
      };
}



Have you tried removing the hash?
